# qt/qml list delegate runs on 5.3, crashes on startup in 5.4+

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qml, versioning

My app with combined C++ and QML lists, has the model implemented in C++, derived from QAbstractListModel, and delegate in QML.

The model has three items stored as QString.

When displaying the list, the delegate has a property *numItems* initialized from model data as shown:

```
property int numItems:
  {
  var tally = 0;
  model.item1.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
  model.item2.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
  model.item3.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
  return tally;
  }
```

In Qt5.3, everything runs fine, regardless of whether there is data in the model or not.

In Qt5.4, Qt5.5, and Qt5.6, however, and with zero code changes, I get a segfault/ signal 11:

> Error Signal Handler: 11
>   [bt] Execution path at Wed Apr  6, 2016  2:04:00 PM:
>   UI/Build/app_x86/debug/(_Z18stiBackTraceToFilei+0x3e)[0x8a29e9]
>   UI/Build/app_x86/debug/(_Z12stiBackTracev+0x1a)[0x8a29a8]
>   UI/Build/app_x86/debug/(_Z21stiErrorSignalHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x14b[0x8a3e73]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d10)[0x7fd23e7d1d10]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0xfafb5)[0x7fd23f54afb5]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(_ZN3QV42IR9Optimizer3runEP17QQmlEnginePrivatebb+0x1c2d)[0x7fd23f55070d]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(_ZN3QV43JIT20InstructionSelection3runEi+0x91)[0x7fd23f5a0cf1]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(_ZN3QV424EvalInstructionSelection7compileEb+0x37)[0x7fd23f52bf37]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x11cfac)[0x7fd23f56cfac]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x2698de)[0x7fd23f6b98de]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26add8)[0x7fd23f6badd8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(_ZN12QQmlDataBlob7tryDoneEv+0x44)[0x7fd23f6b9394]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269ca1)[0x7fd23f6b9ca1]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269f91)[0x7fd23f6b9f91]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26bff8)[0x7fd23f6bbff8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x273da4)[0x7fd23f6c3da4]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26c8ca)[0x7fd23f6bc8ca]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26dfd1)[0x7fd23f6bdfd1]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26e7a8)[0x7fd23f6be7a8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269d59)[0x7fd23f6b9d59]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269f91)[0x7fd23f6b9f91]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26bff8)[0x7fd23f6bbff8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x273da4)[0x7fd23f6c3da4]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26c8ca)[0x7fd23f6bc8ca]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26dfd1)[0x7fd23f6bdfd1]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26e7a8)[0x7fd23f6be7a8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269d59)[0x7fd23f6b9d59]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x269f91)[0x7fd23f6b9f91]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26bff8)[0x7fd23f6bbff8]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x273da4)[0x7fd23f6c3da4]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26c8ca)[0x7fd23f6bc8ca]
>   /usr/share/qt5/install/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5(+0x26dfd1)[0x7fd23f6bdfd1]
>
> [3]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped)

I have found that if I surround the *model.item* block of code with a try...catch I can get it to not crash, but the *console.error()* call in the catch never shows up on the output.

```
property int numItems:
  {
  var tally = 0;
  try
    {
    model.item1.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
    model.item2.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
    model.item3.length > 0 ? tally++ : "";
    }
  catch(err)
    {
    console.error("Exception in tally calculation: " + err)
    }
  return tally;
  }
```

This feels like a bandaid rather than a real solution.  I need to know if I am missing something more fundamental.  Has something changed in the initialization of code starting with Qt5.4?

As you can see from the crash dump, it occurs deep inside of QT/QML libraries.  If I set a breakpoint in my code the crash does not happen, making it look more like a race-condition than a fundamental code issue.

What is going on here?

Comment: You'll need to provide a runnable example. There's not enough to go on here.

Comment: From personal experience, seg faults appear when one tries to access an object in C++ when object is already destroyed or when object is not yet created. Are You sure that model is created and populated before it is accessed from QML? As far as I understand, QML engine is async to Your C++ code, so what might happen is that QML context is created prior model is created and populated with data for QML to access it.

It's quite difficult to give You a better answer as You don't show how and when You create Your model.

Comment: It seems odd that the segfault occurs without the try-catch, and that the catch never executes when try-catch is added.

Comment: Edit timed out....Odd that segfault occurs sans try-catch, but catch never executes with try-catch.  Adding a try would not delay the Qt execution by much, if any.  Also the fact that the error is consistent in 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6 while running with no errors in 5.3 would indicate a difference between 5.3 and 5.4. ==>Try adding an intentional delay in your C++ model code prior to building the model and see if it causes any difference in behavior.  If so, the async looks like the culprit, but does not explain why addition of try-catch under 5.4--5.6 fixes the issue without catch firing.